# JComboBox getSelectedItem

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

New to java and i am unable to see why my action listener is not working on the jcombobox. I think i have followed the other examples on the net to getSelectedItem, but nothing is happening.
FYI, my project is a unit converter (using MVC..hopefully, but that is not my priority).
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.
Thanks, Simon.

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.*;


    public class UnitConverterView extends JFrame{

    //variables and components
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4673040337179571462L;
    private JComboBox<String> unitCategory;

    private JTextField fromValue = new JTextField(7);
    private JComboBox<String> convertFrom;
    private JLabel equalsLabel = new JLabel(" = ");

    private JTextField toValue = new JTextField(7);
    private JComboBox<String> convertTo;


    //constructor
    UnitConverterView(){
    //set up the view and components

        JPanel unitPanel = new JPanel();

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(600,300);

        String[] categories = {"Length","Weight","Speed","Temperature"};
        unitCategory = new JComboBox<>(categories);

        String[] tofromValues = {" "};
        convertFrom = new JComboBox<>(tofromValues);
        convertTo = new JComboBox<>(tofromValues);


        unitPanel.add(unitCategory);

        unitPanel.add(fromValue);
        unitPanel.add(convertFrom);
        unitPanel.add(equalsLabel);
        unitPanel.add(toValue);
        unitPanel.add(convertTo);

        this.add(unitPanel);

    }

    //get value to convert from
    public int getMeasurement() {
        return Integer.parseInt(fromValue.getText());
    }

    //listen for unitCategory to be selected
    void addUnitCategoryListener(ActionListener listenForUnitCategory) {
        unitCategory.addActionListener(listenForUnitCategory);
    }

class UnitCatListener implements ActionListener { 

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            /*String unitSelected = (String) unitCategory.getSelectedItem();
            if (e.getSource() == unitCategory) {
                String unitName = (String) unitCategory.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println("UnitName = " + unitName);
                changeText(unitName);
            }*/

            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
            String unitName = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println("UnitName = " + unitName);

        }

        void changeText(String name) {
            toValue.setText(name);
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell you never add the listener. You need to call `unitCategory.addActionListener(new UnitCatListener())`.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared a method addUnitCategoryListener() for registering listener to the combobox, but you never called this method. That's why the listener is never registered.

Add the below line at the end of your constructor, then you should be fine:

```
addUnitCategoryListener(new UnitCatListener());
```

Answer (score 1):

To simply solve your problem, call the method you created to register the listener on the component. Add this to your constructor:

```
addUnitCategoryListener(new UnitCatListener());
```

However, there are a few things you'll want to know:

- An `ItemListener` will usually do a better job than an `ActionListener` for a `JComboBox`. The previous one does not fire events if the user selects the already selected item (basically, does nothing). Usually there is nothing you need to do in these cases.
- You don't need an extra method just to register the listener, you can directly add to your constructor the line

  ```
  unitCategory.addActionListener(new UnitCatListener());
  ```

  and remove your custom method.
- The methods `changeText` and `getMeasurement` are never used.
- Use parametrized types: instead of `JComboBox` use `JComboBox<String>`.
- You don't need the `equalsLabel` as a field - a local variable will do - since you do not need to reference it anywhere later (unless you plan on changing a property of the label at runtime).

Comment: Thanks for your help. getMeasurement is to get the value of (say inches) to convert from. Have just realised that int is no good for that. changeText prints the calculated value (eg mm). I am not sure about your comment re equalLabel so will research that a bit further.

Comment: @SimonMills Search [here](https://www.google.co.il/search?client=opera&q=java+field+vs+local+variable) for why `equalLabel` should probably be a local variable.